# CNTK ClassificationError > 1

Tags: c#, classification, cntk

What is the expected range of values for CNTKLib.ClassificationError?

I had thought it was similar to a % thus the maximum would be 1 however it seems the values can be > 1. In the training stats below XE = CrossEntropyWithSoftMax and CE = ClassificiationError for models with 5 output categories.

```
    Epoch: 34
    Model 1: XE = 1.503379, CE = 1.506554
    Model 2: XE = 0.5946844, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 3: XE = 1.503184, CE = 0.5913621
    Model 4: XE = 1.510509, CE = 1.503379
    Model 5: XE = 1.510509, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 6: XE = 1.509366, CE = 1.510509
    Model 7: XE = 1.50258, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 8: XE = 1.507859, CE = 0.5946844
    Model 9: XE = 1.501298, CE = 0.5913621
    Model 10: XE = 1.504597, CE = 0.5880399

    Epoch: 35
    Model 1: XE = 1.503288, CE = 0.5946844
    Model 2: XE = 1.512177, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 3: XE = 1.503083, CE = 0.5913621
    Model 4: XE = 1.510375, CE = 0.6013289
    Model 5: XE = 1.506484, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 6: XE = 1.509244, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 7: XE = 1.502508, CE = 0.5980067
    Model 8: XE = 1.507748, CE = 0.5946844
    Model 9: XE = 1.501324, CE = 0.5913621
    Model 10: XE = 1.504497, CE = 0.5880399
```

Answer (score 0):

CNTK seems to use a HardMax activation function for certain sets of parameters. The HardMax is similar to SoftMax in that it returns a value > 0. However, this value may be more than 1.

If we examine [the C++ source](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/3a229624be1dac9529395251775c5dd2a6aeaf95/Source/CNTKv2LibraryDll/Function.cpp) in CNTK for this function, we can see that in action:

```
classificationErrorComposite = Minus(Constant::Scalar(prediction.GetDataType(), 1.0),
TransposeTimes(labelPlaceholder, Hardmax(predictionPlaceholder)));
```

Classification Error is not properly intended a value between 0 and 1. It is a *vector* of difference between the *target* value and the *output value*. [See here.](https://microsoft.github.io/CNTK-R/reference/classification_error.html)

It doesn't tell you how accurate the model is - just how different it is from the target. While that vector *could* be between 0 and 1, it is not guaranteed:

> CNTK defines a classification error (percentage of incorrect predictions) library function rather than a classification accuracy function used by some other libraries [MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt829273.aspx)